# Regex for numbers and a dash

Tags: regex

Im looking for a regular expression for a textbox thats accepts either 10 digits, or 8 digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits. Examples:

```
1212345678
```

or

```
12345678-91
```

Comment: Have you tried making one by yourself? I usually refer to [regexr](http://regexr.com/) for reference.

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: Could you give a list of similar values that should MOT be matched.

Comment: Is there a specific language you are implementing this Regex in ? Implementation varies from one technology to the other - a regex code that works in one language will not necessary work with another one.

Comment: its for asp.net. the values that shouldn't be includes are letters, and it has to be 10 in length (or 11, if the dash is included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if the input is valid without matching any content, this one should be enough:

```
^\d{8}-?\d\d$
```

Beginning with 8 digits, followed (or not) by an optional dash, and another 2 digits up to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

```
((?:^[0-9]{10})|(?:^[0-9]{8}(?:\-\d{2})*))$
```

Input:

```
1212345678
12345678-91
12345678901112-10
1234567890-12
```

Output:

```
1212345678
12345678-91
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/AzbVXt/2

Answer (score 0):

^\d{8}(\d{2})?(-\d{2})?$
^ and $ : match from the begging to the end

\d{8} : 8 digits
(\d{2})? : optional two other digits

(-\d{2})? : optional dash, with two other digits

This will match

1212345678

121234567800

Not 1212345678001

1212345678-

1212345678-00

Not 1212345678-001